# OpenBUGS error in module HostFonts and illegal memory write

Tags: winbugs

Can't find this anywhere else so I thought I'd post a question: Anyone have experience with this OpenBUGS error message?

"Sorry something went wrong in procedure Directory.This in module HostFonts"

I get this error periodically, typically when running larger models, sometimes it happens when I try to sample a parameter, and often it's accompanied by a BlackBox message about an "illegal memory write" which repeatedly pops up until openbugs basically crashes (text dissappears, repeated blackbox messages, etc.

My only theory is this is that I'm storing too many parameter samples, except I don't understand the error message about fonts.  What does this have to do with fonts?

Thanks for any insight you may have!